# Imperial Assignments "Costume" Reward

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My first reward was a costume, so I collected it from the Cargo Bay ... and after that I can't find it.  Can someone tell me where the rewards *appear* after the Cargo Bay ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a special costume and thus it just went into your inventory of other costumes without your notice.

You will be able to find your costumes by going to Menu -> Bitizens -> Dress Up -> Special Costume.